# When should HStoreField be used instead of JSONField?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, hstore, jsonb

Django 1.8 provides HStoreField and Django 1.9 will provide JSONField (which uses jsonb) for PostgreSQL.

My understanding is that hstore is faster than json, but does not allow nesting and only allows strings.

When should one be used over the other? Should one be preferred over the other? Is hstore still the clear winner in performance compared to jsonb?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need indexing, use `jsonb` if you're on 9.4 or newer, otherwise `hstore`. There's really no reason to prefer `hstore` over `jsonb` if both are available.

If you don't need indexing and fast processing and you're just storing and retrieving validated data, use plain `json`. Unlike the other two options this preserves duplicate keys, formatting, key ordering, etc.